# Date validation for invalid years

Tags: ruby, jruby

I am trying to do what feels like something quite basic, but struggling. I want to be able to determine if a date is valid, if it is, parse it and output in a formatted string, else return 'bad date'. This is where I have got so far;

```
require 'date'
date_last_printed = current_item.getProperties['Last Printed']

begin
    d = DateTime.parse(date_last_printed.to_s)
    if Date.valid_date?(d.year, d.month, d.day)
        d.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
    else
        'bad date'
    end
rescue Exception => ex
    ex.message
end
```

However `01/01/1601` is returning as a valid date.

How can I adjust my snippet to return only valid dates (on or after the start of Unix epoch time).

Comment: Actually MSWindows uses 1-1-1601 as [epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1601)

Comment: Well, didn't know that. Every day is a school day!

Comment: I've changed my question slightly based on your comment.

Comment: A) Turn this into a method you can call. B) Actually *print* the output. C) Check that the year is >= 1970.

Comment: Why would you consider `01/01/1601` an invalid date? What are your rules for an valid date?

Answer (score 0):

you could perform epoch conversion inside the begin statement.

```
begin
  raise if (t=Time.parse(date_last_printed)).to_i < 0
  t.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
rescue
  'bad date'
end
```